# Two devices from a common power supply

Tags: power-supply, current

I would like to supply two devices from a single power supply.  The devices are connected to the power supply in parallel. Device1 uses a much higher current than device2. The power supply can safely handle the combined current draw.  My question is if say device1 starts to draw a current (i1, which is larger than device2 can handle), will that current i1 be 'pushed' to device2 and damage it?

Comment: If you switch off you vacuum cleaner, do all your light bulbs go "Poofff" ?

Comment: the only way that you could "push" more current through the device would be by increasing the power supply voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

A power supply connected to two devices is perfectly fine if power supply can supply enough current to power up both devices simultaneously.

That's how all ac appliances are wired up. Your bulb is in parallel with your air conditioner and they work fine together.

Problem might occur when one device gets damaged and it further damages the power supply (rare chance because typically power supplies have short protection. things should start working fine if you disconnect the faulty device). In this case your second device might not get sufficient power to perform its tasks correctly.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

When you have two devices in parallel their currents are independent. If i1 changes it has no effect on i2, as long as the power supply is able to keep the sum of both currents flowing.